# How to execute shell script from suid binaries

Tags: root-access, shell

I've a rooted phone and created a `root:root` owned binary with `suid` bit set. It's supposed to be a wrapper for a shell script that needs root to work. Calling `system("/system/bin/sh ./script")` doesn't have the desired effect -- script still doesn't get root privilages. I tried calling `setuid(0); setgid(0)` in my wrapper, but that doesn't work. How do I run suid scripts on Android?

Comment: Can you post your full code?